# Laravel 4 - File not deleting using File::delete

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im having a problem deleting a file from my server after if has been 'Downloaded'.

The File::delete() method works everywhere else in my app apart from the following:

```
return Response::download( $tmpFile, $document->documentname );

File::delete( $tmpFile );
```

Any help on why this is happening would be great.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `return` from your function, it **obviously** makes the rest of the function not execute.

The `File::delete()` is *never* called.

---

I see what you want now.. well, if you load the file into memory (`file_get_contents`), then you can delete the file on disk, and send the loaded data to browser.

You'll have to send the right headers etc youself, but it should work.

Comment: That would make sense ... What would be the best way of deleting the file after its been downloaded?

Comment: @BigJobbies Fire an event! Check out the events documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/events

Comment: see updated. That'sn how I'd do it. Maybe events could work as well, but I am not familiar with them yet.

Comment: @JoelHinz - Can an event be fired after the return Response?

Comment: No, you fire it before returning. If that delete's the file too early, you can queue the event.

Comment: @JoelHinz you sure this is safe? If the file is huge, the user may still be downloading while you delete it.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing myself

Comment: You have a point. I was only thinking about documents, as in the example. I suppose you'd have to check your server log files if you really want to be sure, which is cumbersome. Or you could just soft delete it, then run a cron job to remove older soft deletes daily.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
return response()->download($filename)->deleteFileAfterSend($filename);
```

Comment: A little explanation or docs link would boost the quality of your answer.